# Padding appears at bottom of UniformGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have the below XAML which shows some padding under the buttons in the UniformGrid:

```
<Grid>
  <UniformGrid Background="#CCC"
               HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
               VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
               Margin="8,8,8,0">
    <Button Height="28"
            Margin="5">
      OK
    </Button>
    <Button Height="28"
            Margin="5">
      Cancel
    </Button>
  </UniformGrid>
</Grid>
```

It displays as:

[image: 2 Buttons]

But if I remove one of the buttons, no padding will occur:

[image: 1 Button]

How can I remove this padding when 2 buttons are in the XAML?

I have tried the obvious `Padding` and `Margin` properties but it remains the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try specifying the number of rows:

```
<UniformGrid Rows="1" />
```

UniformGrid will automatically set the number of columns and rows according to the number of elements added to it. Take a look at this [post](http://wpf.2000things.com/2012/01/13/472-uniformgrid-defaults-to-being-square/).

Comment: Thanks, this is better than my answer of setting the columns.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that setting the number of columns = 2 will fix the problem, as in:

```
<UniformGrid Columns="2" />
```

Although I still don't know why this won't work without setting the columns, if anyone can explain I would appreciate.